# hyperlink issue dont redirect to another webpage when click on the menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
          $('.mobile-nav-button').on('click', function() {
          $( ".mobile-nav-button .mobile-nav-button__line:nth-of-type(1)" ).toggleClass( "mobile-nav-button__line--1");
          $( ".mobile-nav-button .mobile-nav-button__line:nth-of-type(2)" ).toggleClass( "mobile-nav-button__line--2");  
          $( ".mobile-nav-button .mobile-nav-button__line:nth-of-type(3)" ).toggleClass( "mobile-nav-button__line--3");  
          
          $('.mobile-menu').toggleClass('mobile-menu--open');
          return false;
        }); 
        });
```

```css
 
.mobile-nav-button {
  width: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 2rem;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 35px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

.mobile-nav-button .mobile-nav-button__line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background: #0e0e0e;
  position: relative;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.mobile-nav-button .mobile-nav-button__line:nth-of-type(2) { margin: 0.5rem 0; }

.mobile-nav-button .mobile-nav-button__line--1 {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 13px;
  position: absolute;
}

.mobile-nav-button .mobile-nav-button__line--2 { display: none; }

.mobile-nav-button .mobile-nav-button__line--3 {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  top: 13px;
  position: absolute;
}

.mobile-menu {
  display: block;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  right: -100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fcb852;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9998;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 587px; /*height of  opened menu*/
}

.mobile-menu ul {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 0;
}

.mobile-menu ul li { list-style: none; }

.mobile-menu ul li a {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0e0e0e;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.mobile-menu ul li a:after {
  content: '';
  background: #0e0e0e;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: -100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}

.mobile-menu ul li a:hover { color: #fff; }

.mobile-menu ul li a:hover:after { right: 0; }

.mobile-menu img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  top: 3rem;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.mobile-menu--open {
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
} 

.control {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.menu{
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
            <div class="mobile-nav-button">
                <div class="mobile-nav-button__line"></div>
                <div class="mobile-nav-button__line"></div>
                <div class="mobile-nav-button__line"></div>
            </div>
            <nav class="mobile-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about1.php">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">What We Do</a></li>
                    <li><a href="getinvolved.php">Get Involved</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

hello here i have designed simple menu bar. i have some menu in it & for each menu i have one web page with .php extension but when i click on the menu it wont redirect me to the another page.that means there is no operation performed when i click on menu

Comment: maybe add `/` before the links ? and check if the path is correct

Comment: I dont understand .you need to `page redirection` or `prevent the page redirection`?

Comment: i want to redirect to the page suppose if i click on contact us menu it should redirect to the contact us page . & i have added '/' before the file name but nothing is going to happen..

Comment: but when i right click on the menu & click on open in new tab the page will display in new tab

Comment: try adding target="_blank" in the a tag. Ex <a href="index.php" target="_blank">Home</a>

Comment: It works fine in the code snippet you have shown here. Please create a [mcve] that makes the problem reproducible.

Answer (score -1):

this will help you to disable your href tag.

```css
a.disabled {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<a href="hai.html" class="disabled">Click here</a>
```